# How can I strip text from string?

Tags: javascript, string, null, substring, match

I have one variable holding single line string which is html element like this.

```
var des = "<p> --Sometext before-- FI: This is fi name, This is fi manufacturer <br /> SE:This is se name, This is se manufacturer <br /> EN: This is en name, This is en manufacturer</p>";
```

I want to select everything after FI: until comma sign into one variable and after comma sign until 
 tag into another variable. Also for SE: and EN: too.

For example, result will be like this.

```
    var fi_name         = "This is fi name";
    var fi_manufacturer = "This is fi manufacturer";
    var se_name         = "This is se name";
    var se_manufacturer = "This is se manufacturer";
    var en_name         = "This is en name";
    var en_manufacturer = "This is en manufacturer";
```

Note, the string change dynamically but still have same pattern.

For example:

```
<p> --Sometext before-- FI:[name],[manufacturer]<br/ >SE:[name],[manufacturer]<br/ >FI:[name],[manufacturer]</p>
```

You can have a look at demo in [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/raPDd/).

Now it's throwing null error.

Edited v v v

It's not working in live website. The des variable is fully look like this.
Please see http://jsfiddle.net/AM8X2/ It's throwing null again.

Comment: Update the question with the code you added in the jsfiddle.

Comment: See http://jsfiddle.net/raPDd/1/ is it what you want?

Comment: No. It's almost want I want but name and manufacturer has to be separated into variables

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed your jsFiddle to this:

http://jsfiddle.net/11684/raPDd/4/

I added upper case letters and spaces and comma's to your regex, so it doesn't return null (because no match was found) and the rest was fine.
The result:

```
var fi,se,en;
var des = "<p>FI: This is fi name, This is fi manufacturer <br /> SE:This is se name, This is se manufacturer <br /> EN: This is en name, This is en manufacturer</p>";

var match = des.match(/<p>FI:([a-zA-Z ,]+)<br \/> SE:([a-zA-Z ,]+)<br \/> EN:([a-zA-Z ,]+)<\/p>/);
fi = match[1];
se = match[2];
en = match[3];

alert("[FI]: " + fi + "\n[SE]:" + se + "\n[EN]:" + en);​
```

**EDIT:**
I didn't see you needed the name and manufacturer in separate variables, I edited the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/11684/raPDd/5/ to this:

```
var fi,se,en;
var des = "<p>FI: This is fi name, This is fi manufacturer <br /> SE:This is se name, This is se manufacturer <br /> EN: This is en name, This is en manufacturer</p>";

var match = des.match(/<p>FI:([a-zA-Z ,]+)<br \/> SE:([a-zA-Z ,]+)<br \/> EN:([a-zA-Z ,]+)<\/p>/);
fi = match[1];
se = match[2];
en = match[3];

//After that just split on the comma:

var fi_name = fi.split(",")[0];
var fi_manu = fi.split(",")[1];
var en_name = en.split(",")[0];
var en_manu = en.split(",")[1];
var se_name = se.split(",")[0];
var se_manu = se.split(",")[1];
​
```

Comment: It's not working in live site. See http://jsfiddle.net/AM8X2/ for full des string.

Comment: @PakinaiKamolpus I'd give that `<p>` an ID, use `document.getElementById("thatID");` and apply the regex to its innerHTML after removing `<p>` and `</p>` from the regex.

Answer (score 2):

You can just look for the specified pattern and extract the relevant information from there:

```
var des = "<p>FI: This is fi name, This is fi manufacturer <br /> SE:This is se name, This is se manufacturer <br /> EN: This is en name, This is en manufacturer</p>";

var f = function(w, s) {
    return new RegExp(w + ':([^,]+)').exec(s)[1];
}

fi = f('FI', des);
se = f('SE', des);
en = f('EN', des);
```

`w + ':([^,]+)'` can be explained as: get me the value after the colon of `w` in `s`

here is the updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/raPDd/2/).

---

A more complete solution, one that handles all HTML tags would be the following:

```
var f = function(w, s) {
    var el = document.createElement('div'), arr;
    el.innerHTML = s;

    arr = (new RegExp(w + ':([^\n]+)').exec(el.innerText)[1]).split(',');

    return {
        manufacturer: arr[1],
        name: arr[0]       
    }
}

fi = JSON.stringify(f('FI', des));
se = JSON.stringify(f('SE', des));
en = JSON.stringify(f('EN', des));
```

The fiddle for this is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/epoch/jdZdv/)

To access any of these in variables (without the `JSON.stringify()`, the direct method return, i.e. `f('SE', des)`), you would do:

```
// for fi manufacturer
fi.manufacturer

// for en name
en.name

// etc..
```

in my opinion, by using this, you have a much more modular approach, and less chance of error.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. But what's about manufacturer? It's showing just names. I want manufacturer too. :)

Answer (score 1):

Here's a possible solution:

```
var des = "<p> --Sometext before-- FI: This is fi name, This is fi manufacturer <br /> SE:This is se name, This is se manufacturer <br /> EN: This is en name, This is en manufacturer</p>";

​var matches = des.match( /([A-Z]{2}):\s*([^,]+?)\s*,\s*([^<$]+?)\s*(?=<|$)/g );

var results = [];

for ( var i = 0; i < matches.length; i++ ) {
    var res = matches[ i ].match( /([A-Z]{2}):\s*([^,]+?)\s*,\s*([^<$]+?)\s*(?=<|$)/ );
    var abbr = res[ 1 ].toLowerCase();

    results[ abbr + '_name' ] = res[ 2 ];
    results[ abbr + '_manufacturer' ] = res[ 3 ];
}

console.log( results );
```

​Try it out in this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/bukfixart/QB5qu/

Comment: Thank you for your reply. But I need those variables for using not an array. Can you edit?

Comment: @PakinaiKamolpus See my answer for that.